# How to mock an object in a unit test?

Tags: python, class, testing, mocking, patch

I am working on a unit test where I want to mock a class within a new class I am testing.

Below there is my simplified code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, path:str):
        self.path = path
        self.pres = Presentation(path)

@patch("pptx.Presentation")
def test_init(mock_presentation):
    MyClass(path="path")
```

I'm getting the following error because the test is trying to run the `Presentation` class, but I want it to be mocked instead.

`>       raise PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file) E       pptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at ''`

How can I mock the class correctly?

Comment: `MyClass.__init__` uses the global variable `Presentation`, not the module attribute `pptx.Presentation`, to instantiate the class. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the `__init__()` method of your class `MyClass` to pass it an instance of `Presentation`. On my opinion this is a practice useful for testing and developing software in general and it is a valid solution for your question.
I mean that it is better to instantiate an object and pass the instance as parameter to the `__init__()` method than instantiate the object directly inside the `__init__()` as you do in your code.

The test code becomes:

```
from unittest import mock
import unittest
from pptx import Presentation

class MyClass:
    # -------> added the parameter pres (Presentation type)
    def __init__(self, path:str, pres:Presentation):
        self.path = path
        #self.pres = Presentation(path)
        self.pres = pres

class TestPptx(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("pptx.Presentation")
    def test_init(self, mock_presentation):
        # -----> add the mock object in the instantiation
        MyClass(path="path", pres=mock_presentation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

I hope is enough for you.

Comment: @Roma V is this answer is useful? Please give me a feeback